# Java8 - Search values in a Map

Tags: java, java-8

I'm learning Java8 and looking to see how you could convert the following into Java8 streaming API where it 'stops' after finding the first 'hit' (like in the code below)

```
public int findId(String searchTerm) {

    for (Integer id : map.keySet()) {
        if (map.get(id).searchTerm.equalsIgnoreCase(searchTerm))
            return id;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: When you need to key and value, you are usually better off iterating over the `entrySet()`

Comment: Is your map's contents reasonably constant? And can keys ever match other keys case insensitively?

Answer (score 12):

Without testing, something like this should work :

```
return map.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .filter(e-> e.getValue().searchTerm.equalsIgnoreCase(searchTerm))
          .findFirst() // process the Stream until the first match is found
          .map(Map.Entry::getKey) // return the key of the matching entry if found
          .orElse(-1); // return -1 if no match was found
```

This is a combination of searching for a match in the Stream of the `entrySet` and returning either the key if a match is found or -1 otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the [Stream#findFirst()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) method once you have filtered the Stream using your predicate.  Something like this:

```
map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(searchTerm))
    .findFirst();
```

This will return an [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) as there may not be any elements left after the filtering.

Comment: You have missed to return `-1` if there is no match.

Comment: @CrazyNinja Yes that's true - Eran's answer above is basically the same but with the mapping to the Integer key.  I think in a Java 8 world you would more likely return an Optional<Integer> than -1, though that would depend on any contracts you have with client code.

Comment: @tchambers Yeah that really depends on the contract indeed but OPs contract seem to return `-1` so I would stick to that.